# FFT:WoL, First battle is just me and Delita, no back up?

Tags: android, final-fantasy-tactics

Since it is Cyber Week on Android, and FFT:WoL was at a <s>just</s> abordable price, and my PSP is almost dead, I brought it.

The controls are... quirky, but the intro battle goes fine, first chapter begin, go kill thoses thiefs, yadda yadda...

Except when I remebered being evenly matched against the thieves on PSP, I only have Delita and Ramza on android?
With such weighted dices, I have no chances to win that battle, and losing is a real game over.

I am currently redownloading it and will try to start again, but should I expect the same from a bug/change from the PSP version? Did I started the "Ultra Hard" mode somehow?

Answer (score 3):

**You should be able to place additional units.**

I actually had this same "problem" when I first played the game on the PlayStation. During the pre-battle phase where you place Ramza, it should be possible to sideswipe or something to get the next available unit for placement; there's just no documentation of this fact in-game, even during the tutorial.